# .htaccess rewrite all contents from subdomain to domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I rewrited a subdomain to a section on my site:

`https://music.example.com` points to `https://example.com/section.php?url=music`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^music.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ section.php?url=music/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But I need to use the same images, css, etc. for this (and other) subdomains.

`https://example.com/images/img.jpg`
Should be accessible from `https://music.example.com/images/img.jpg`

I tried to find a solution but I might not be doing the right search.

Comment: As @MrWhite says, it's a rewrite instead of redirect. Thanks. I don't know if I can change the title now...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^music.example.com
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ section.php?url=music/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
> ```

This rule *internally rewrites* (not "redirects") a request of the form `music.example.com/<anything>` to `section.php?url=music/<anything>`. ie. Everything, including all images and CSS etc. This is much more than stated in your description, in which you only want the root directory to "point to" `https://example.com/section.php?url=music`.

If you only want the root directory to be rewritten then restrict the regex `^(.*)$` to only match the root.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^music\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^$ section.php?url=music [QSA,L]
```

NB: Don't forget to backslash-escape the literal dots in the regex.

This now naturally excludes everything else from being rewritten, except for requests to the subdomain's root directory, ie. `https://music.example.com/` only.

> .htaccess redirect all contents from subdomain to domain

As noted above, this is an internal "rewrite", not an external "redirect". And neither does this rewrite from subdomain to domain. The requested hostname does not change and it is assumed that both the subdomain and domain apex point to the same place on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work. The problem is that the links to the images and the css sheets are pointing to https://example.com/music/images/img.jpg but that redirection is not working.
I think there are two parts to this:
1. There is already a link pointing to a section: https://example.com/music -> https://example.com/section.php?url=music and now I have a subdomain pointing to the same place. This is working.
2. The internal contents (images and css sheets) are not being redirected.
Maybe I should use an additional statement?